# Words for classification of jobs according to their accrued interest

Tags: expressions, vocabulary

I'm not a native English speaker.

I remember having read an article comparing jobs according to how the worker accrue value over time, i.e. the more your work and acquire experience, the more valuable you are.

For ex. a knowledge worker = a software engineer will accrue a lot of experience over jobs. A manager as well, being exposed to a lot of work experience.

On the other hand, an employee selling shoes in a small shop or a waiter bringing food in a restaurant is accruing less experience benefits over time, or can even drop, for ex. a young waiter / seller being seen as more desirable.

**I'm looking for words to describe this kind of difference in jobs, in order to find articles / research on this subject**. I tried a lot of word combinations in search engines, without being able to find relevant articles or wikipedia pages.

Answer (score 1):

The concept you’re looking for is called *human capital*.  Wikipedia’s article is a good overview.

In the example you use, you could say that working as an engineer or manager contributes more to an individual’s human capital than working as a waiter.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_capital

Comment: Human capital is at company level. Would you have a variant at an individual point of view?